# Markers disappear

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, marker

I trying to set marker visible on the map when I am in range and set invisible when i am not in range. When   am moving and enter area marker appear - but when I get out of range marker is still visible. Here is my code `onLocationUpdate`.
I iterate over my database and adding markers. `getDeviceLocation` return `Ltglng` with my current location. I implement this also for GPS provider. Any ideas will be helpfull ty!

```
 locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Cursor res = activityA.myDB.getAllData();
                while (res.moveToNext()) {

                    double ltd = Double.valueOf(res.getString(3));
                    double lng = Double.valueOf(res.getString(4));
                    LatLng hole = new LatLng(ltd, lng);
                    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hole)
                            .title(res.getString(1)).visible(false));

                 if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(getDeviceLocation(), marker.getPosition()) <3 ) {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    } 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have provided this is what I can gather.

You are adding the marker (originally set to invisible), and then if it meets your if statement, you make them invisible. The problem is, I don't see any place, where you would make them invisible again, or remove them.

Do you save these markers in your activity? For example in an ArrayList?

I have two suggestions:

1)Either call mMap.clear() before before your while statement. This will clear the map of any markers, and then adds the new ones as they are created.

2)Save all your markers in an ArrayList and then in your onLocationChanged, use a for loop to go through all your markers and make the ones out of range invisible. Here is an example:

```
for (Marker marker: mMarkerArrayList) {
    if (outOfRange()) {
        marker.visible(false);
    }
}
```

Here mMarkerArrayList is the ArrayList containing all your markers. outOfRange() is a helper function that returns a boolean if the marker is outOfRange.

Comment: I save my markers in database. Tryed now to add them in list  but still the same only when i refresh the map its disappear , not when i moving out of range. Now will try with map clear @Khash

Comment: With mMap.clear() its working somehow. I dont find any logic why  its not working  the others ways but  now its ok.Thank alot @Khash!

Comment: It is hard to say why the first method you tried is not working without looking at all your code. But I am glad the clear() method works.